# seaborn jointplot axes don't match after adding a colorbar

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I am using seaborn to create a jointplot with kind='hist'. When I add the colorbar for the histogram to the plot the grid for the jointplot and the single histogram no longer match. I am pretty sure this is because I add the colorbar to the axis, but I have no idea how to do it differently and wasn't able to find anything helpful here or elsewhere.

```py
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable

#Function I use to generate some sampling weights (my real data is very imbalanced)
def generate_weights(n_bins:int, data:np.ndarray)->np.ndarray:
    hist_data, bin_edges = np.histogram(data, bins=n_bins)
    indices = np.digitize(data, bin_edges[:-1])-1
    weights = 1.0/hist_data[indices]
    return weights

#generating some data to plot
dataset_1 = np.random.normal(0, 50, size=1000)
dataset_2 = np.random.normal(9, 55, size=1000)

#generating weights for the data
weights_1 = generate_weights(50, dataset_1)
#weights_2 = generate_weights(50, dataset_2)

#calculate the min and max of both datasets to use them later for calculating the bins and for the limits of the axes
min_val = min([np.min(dataset_1), np.min(dataset_2)])
max_val = max([np.max(dataset_1), np.max(dataset_2)])

bin_width = (max_val-min_val)/100
# calculate bins
bins_2d = (np.linspace(min_val, max_val, 100), np.linspace(min_val, max_val, 100))

sns.set_style('darkgrid')
figsize = (8,6)
jointplot_hist = sns.jointplot(
    x = dataset_1,
    y = dataset_2,
    kind = 'hist',
    cmap = 'viridis',
    bins = bins_2d,
    **{'weights': weights_1}
)

#set axis labels
jointplot_hist.set_axis_labels('dataset 1', 'dataset_2')

#set axis limits
jointplot_hist.ax_joint.set_xlim([min_val, max_val])
jointplot_hist.ax_joint.set_ylim([min_val, max_val])

#plot a diagonal line
plt.plot([min_val, max_val], [min_val, max_val], color='red', linestyle='-', linewidth=0.5)

#here I add the colorbar
divider = make_axes_locatable(jointplot_hist.ax_joint)
cax = divider.append_axes('right', size='5%', pad=0.05)

mappable = jointplot_hist.ax_joint.collections[0]
plt.colorbar(mappable, cax=cax)
```

Plot where the grid no longer matches:

[image: Plot where the grid no longer matches]

I tried to set the colorbar differently, like this:

```py
cbar_ax = jointplot_hist.fig.add_axes([0.85, 0.15, 0.05, 0.7])  
mappable = jointplot_hist.ax_joint.collections[0]  
jointplot_hist.fig.colorbar(mappable, cax=cbar_ax)
```

but then I do not have it placed between the jointplot and the individual plot which is the design I would like to get. Also adjusting the size is tricky.

Comment: See [Getting colorbar in a hex jointplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29096632/getting-colorbar-in-a-hex-jointplot)

Comment: @JohanC This would be my go to solution if nothing else works, but I would prefer to have the colorbar placed where it is in my example. Thank you though, this is a nice simple solution if what I want to achieve is not possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can grab the position of both the joint ax, and the marginal ax. And then reposition the right of the marginal ax.

```py
# at the end of the code in the question's post
jointplot_hist.fig.canvas.draw() # a draw is needed to let matplotlib fix the positions
_jx0, _jy0, jx1, _jy1 = jointplot_hist.ax_joint.get_position().bounds
mx0, my0, _mx1, my1 = jointplot_hist.ax_marg_x.get_position().bounds
jointplot_hist.ax_marg_x.set_position([mx0, my0, jx1, my1])
```

PS: Note that to set the figsize, `sns.jointplot()` uses the `height=` parameter (and creates a square plot). You can use `jointplot_hist.fig.set_size_inches(8, 6)` to change the size, once everything has been created.